# Deserialize portion of XmlDocument into object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I see this question often enough, but nobody's title really seems to depict their question.  I get a large response object back from a Web API that contains general response information, along with the data object I want to deserialize.

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <status>
      <apiErrorCode>0</apiErrorCode>
      <apiErrorMessage/>
      <dbErrorCode>0</dbErrorCode>
      <dbErrorMessage/>
      <dbErrorList/>
  </status>
<data>
    <modelName>ReportXDTO</modelName>
    <modelData>
        <id>1780</id>
        <reportTitle>Access Level (select) with Door Assignment</reportTitle>
        <hasParameters>true</hasParameters>
        <parameters>
            <dataType>STRING</dataType>
            <title>Access Level:</title>
            <index>1</index>
            <allowMulti>true</allowMulti>
            <selectSql>SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM dbo.[Levels] WHERE [PrecisionFlag] = '0' ORDER BY [Name] </selectSql>
            <values>
                <value>Door 1</value>
                <used>1</used>
            </values>
            <values>
                <value>Door 2</value>
                <used>1</used>
            </values>
            <values>
                <value>Door 3</value>
                <used>1</used>
            </values>
       </parameters>
       <sourceSql>SELECT [Name], [SData] FROM [Schedules]</sourceSql>
       <report/>
   </modelData>
   <itemReturned>1</itemReturned>
   <itemTotal>1</itemTotal>
</data>
<listInfo>
    <pageIdRequested>1</pageIdRequested>
    <pageIdCurrent>1</pageIdCurrent>
    <pageIdFirst>1</pageIdFirst>
    <pageIdPrev>1</pageIdPrev>
    <pageIdNext>1</pageIdNext>
    <pageIdLast>1</pageIdLast>
    <itemRequested>1</itemRequested>
    <itemReturned>1</itemReturned>
    <itemStart>1</itemStart>
    <itemEnd>1</itemEnd>
    <itemTotal>1</itemTotal>
</listInfo>
</root>
```

I only want to deserialize the modelData element.  The modelData object type is dynamic, depending on the API call.

I deserialize xml in other applications, and created the following method, but don't know how to specifically ONLY get the modelData element:

```
    public static T ConvertXmltoClass<T>(HttpResponseMessage http, string elementName) where T : new()
    {
        var newClass = new T();

        try
        {
            var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(http.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, "root");

            XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
            reader.ReadToFollowing(elementName);

            //The xml needs to show the proper object name
            var xml = reader.ReadOuterXml().Replace(elementName, newClass.GetType().Name);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                newClass = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AppLog.LogException(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, e);
        }

        return newClass;
    }
```

I have updated this thread multiple times now, to stay current.  I started updating it with the first solution.  But that solution by itself didn't solve the problem.  With the code how it is right now, I get no exceptions, but don't get the xml deserialized to my object.  Instead I get a new, blank object.  Thoughts?

THOUGH the object type can change, here is my current object I am dealing with: (PLEASE NOTE, that I deserialize the exact xml in modelData, in the Web API)

```
namespace WebApiCommon.DataObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ReportXDto
    {
        public ReportXDto()
        {
            Parameters = new List<ReportParameterXDto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public bool HasParameters { get; set; } = false;
        public List<ReportParameterXDto> Parameters { get; set; }
        public string SourceSql { get; set; }
        public DataTable Report { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ReportXDto
    {
        public ReportXDto()
        {
            Parameters = new List<ReportParameterXDto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public bool HasParameters { get; set; } = false;
        public List<ReportParameterXDto> Parameters { get; set; }
        public string SourceSql { get; set; }
        public DataTable Report { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ReportParameterValuesXDto
    {
        public string Value { get; set; } = "";
        public bool Used { get; set; } = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want to do.  Why are you converting from JSON to XML?   Why not deserialize directly from JSON?  Also, why `XmlDocument` and not `XDocument`?

Comment: The Web API I get the data from, returns a json response.  The deserializing from json to an XmlDocument, works great, and I use that method in many other applications.  This problem though is unique, because the modelData returned in the API response, is XML.

Comment: I'm at a point of not caring what solution I have to implement, as long as I can deserialize the modelData into my T object.

Comment: You can deserialize directly from an `XmlNode` by using `ProperXmlNodeReader` from [Deserialize object property with StringReader vs XmlNodeReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30115691/3744182) and [c#, XML How to cycle through an XML node fetched with XMLNode.SelectSingleNode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36582657/3744182).  Or if you switch to LINQ to XML you could use `XObjectExtensions.Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element)` from [Changing type of element in XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278016).

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem now?  Is it that the element name `<modelData>` doesn't match the root element name of the type `T` to which you are trying to deserialize?  Can you provide a [mcve] that includes the type `T` into which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: I changed modelData to the T object GetType.Name, which made the solution stop throwing an exception, because the xml now matched the object class.  HOWEVER, I only get back a blank object.

Comment: Also, I have tried using both a MemoryStream and a StringReader.  Both result in a blank object.

Comment: To help you, I think we may need a [mcve] that shows the type(s).  Possibly some namespaces somewhere are not matching.

Comment: Oh, this looks relevant: [How to deserialize a node in a large document using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680420/3744182).

Comment: Very simple.  Very common mistake.  After filling a memory stream, you have to set the position to zero before reading.

Comment: Sorry, can you please be more specific as to what you think the issue is?

Comment: [`XmlSerializer` is case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2451997).  All of your properties are Pascal Case but the XML element names are camel Case, so nothing will get deserialized.

Comment: You just made my eyes go wide open.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    Thank you dbc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `XmlSerializer` is case sensitive.  Thus your property names need to match the XML element names exactly -- unless overridden with an [attribute that controls XML serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) such as [`[XmlElement(ElementName="id")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdsk9t4x.aspx).  To generate a data model with the correct casing I used http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ which resulted in:

```
public class ReportParameterValuesXDto 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="used")]
    public string Used { get; set; }
}

public class ReportParametersXDto 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="dataType")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="index")]
    public string Index { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="allowMulti")]
    public string AllowMulti { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="selectSql")]
    public string SelectSql { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="values")]
    public List<ReportParameterValuesXDto> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ReportXDto 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="reportTitle")]
    public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="hasParameters")]
    public string HasParameters { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="parameters")]
    public ReportParametersXDto Parameters { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="sourceSql")]
    public string SourceSql { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="report")]
    public string Report { get; set; }
}
```

(After generating the model, I modified the class names to match your naming convention.)

Given the correct data model, you can deserialize directly from a selected `XmlNode` using an [`XmlNodeReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.aspx) as shown in [How to deserialize a node in a large document using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680420/3744182) without having to re-serialize to an intermediate XML string.  The following extension method does the trick:

```
public static partial class XmlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeElements<T>(this XmlNode root, string localName, string namespaceUri)
    {
        return new XmlNodeReader(root).DeserializeElements<T>(localName, namespaceUri);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeElements<T>(this XmlReader reader, string localName, string namespaceUri)
    {
        var serializer = XmlSerializerFactory.Create(typeof(T), localName, namespaceUri);
        while (!reader.EOF)
        {
            if (!(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == localName && reader.NamespaceURI == namespaceUri))
                reader.ReadToFollowing(localName, namespaceUri);

            if (!reader.EOF)
            {
                yield return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                // Note that the serializer will advance the reader past the end of the node
            }               
        }
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializerFactory
{
    // To avoid a memory leak the serializer must be cached.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer
    // This factory taken from 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128757/wrap-properties-with-cdata-section-xml-serialization-c-sharp/34138648#34138648

    readonly static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer> cache;
    readonly static object padlock;

    static XmlSerializerFactory()
    {
        padlock = new object();
        cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type serializedType, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        if (serializedType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (rootName == null && rootNamespace == null)
            return new XmlSerializer(serializedType);
        lock (padlock)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            var key = Tuple.Create(serializedType, rootName, rootNamespace);
            if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out serializer))
                cache[key] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializedType, new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = rootName, Namespace = rootNamespace });
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would deserialize as follows:

```
var modelData = doc.DeserializeElements<ReportXDto>("modelData", "").FirstOrDefault();
```

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8khFr0).

Answer (score 0):

For Huge xml files always use XmlReader so you do not get an out of memory issue.  See code below to get the element as a string :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //or Create(Stream)
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("modelData");
            if (!reader.EOF)
            {
                string modelDataStr = reader.ReadOuterXml();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK.... so in my case, where I am passed in the XML from the response of an API call.... and I need to deserialize only the elements within the modelData element, how do I get to it?

Comment: var reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
                    reader.ReadToFollowing(elementName);
    reader.ReadOuterXml();   //This doesn't get me the object.  Nether does reader.ReadInnerXml()

Comment: Is the object null?  Are you using a filename or a stream? I assume it is coming from http.Content but wasn't sure if you were going to read a string or a stream.  I tested with xml posted and it got correct element so make sure you got the proper response.

Comment: I have the XmlDocument created from the JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode.  XmlReader.Create(doc.InnerXml), it throws an exception

Comment: XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);  reader.ReadToFollowing(elementName);  reader.ReadOuterXml();      //This doesn't fail until I attempt to deserialize the stream

Comment: A linq statement doesn't get executed until the instruction that uses the output.  So you do not get an error on the ReadToFollowing().  The root element of an xml must be a single node.  It cannot be an array.  I can't tell if the error is occurring on the Read of serialize. You can hover mouse on reader to check if it is null.  I don't think it will be.  So the issue is with the root object of the deserialize.  You could test by putting the xml into a file and see if it works from a file.

Comment: You still need to have the parent element so you have only one node at the root of the xml.

Comment: jdweng, I have now updated my question and code above to include your suggestion... and the problem.